# Retrieve Nth item from ArrayList gives IndexOutOfBoundsException even when index is in range?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList and I am trying to measure the time it takes to retrieve an item from the middle of my ArrayList.

Here it is:

```
  List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        cars.add(new Car(null, i));
```

How would I retrieve item 500000?

I tried creating a variable like int example = 500000, then put cars.get(example). But I just got errors:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 500000, Size: 1

Here why am I getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException even when the index I requested < total entries?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Tutorial on lists: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html ArrayList documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html General Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ Based on the nature of your question and subsequent problem, you will be well served by reading those. This is basic stuff that is covered entirely within the first few sentences of those documents.

Comment: Also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html `IndexOutOfBoundsException` means *exactly* what its name implies.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `get()` function

```
cars.get(500000);
```

**EDIT**

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` means you are trying to retrieve an information that is beyond the list.

Your error is not related to the function you're using, you are probably making a mistake somewhere else. Please realize whether you're populating and trying to read from the same variable.

Comment: I get an error, as posted in the OP.

Comment: If there are a million items in the list, and I am trying to retrieve item 500000, thats not beyond the list?

Comment: @user1902535 No, but somehow your list does not contain 1 million items. It contains 1. Do some prints to find out why/where.

Comment: @user1902535 Do some basic troubleshooting. Print a stack trace; find the error. Try reading the linked tutorials as well.

Comment: @user1902535 That's totally true, IF it has 1 million it is not beyond the list. But your stack trace indicates it has only one item. `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 500000, Size: 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your list is named car, but you are adding to a list named cars.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an indexed collection of data you would likely want to use something other than an ArrayList.... consider a HashMap for example:

```
HashMap<Integer, Car> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    map.put(i, new Car(null, i));
}

Car c = map.get(500000);
```

Comment: You'd have to actually add the items to the map, and add it with a key.

Comment: I'm doing HashMap after I've done ArrayList. I'm comparing the times of all of them.

Comment: @user1902535 I think you need to learn a bit more about the language basics before you start concerning yourself with benchmarking collections.

Comment: Premature copy/paste issue, apologies.

Comment: @rolfl Your advice is potentially good, but please be careful giving this type of advice to new programmers -- merely wanting to create an indexed collection of data in itself is not a sufficient reason to use a map instead (you want to consider common operations, nature of data, sparseness, etc. when choosing an appropriate container). If *all* you want to do is create an indexed collection of data, you would most definitely want to start off with a `List` of some sort, which is precisely an indexed collection of data.